# Duvida sobre CSS em herança

Tags: css

[image: Herança.]

A configuração do Pai 'li' não esta sendo herdada pelos filhos 'li#foto01' e 'li#foto02' não entendo porque

Comment: Coloque também o código do html para podermos ver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você define a propriedade `background`, na verdade você está definindo uma lista de propriedades com os seguintes valores padrões:

- `background-image: none`
- `background-position: 0% 0%`
- `background-size: auto auto`
- `background-repeat: repeat`
- `background-origin: padding-box`
- `background-clip: border-box`
- `background-attachment: scroll`
- `background-color: transparent`

Então você sobrescreve o valor de `background-position`

Para corrigir isso você pode:

- Inverter a ordem (colocar o estilo `ul#album-fotos li` depois)
- Colocar o `!important` depois da propriedade `background-position` (método não recomendado)
- Trcar `background` por `background-image` e `background-repeat`